# Nested Grid TapGestureRecognizer not working?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, uigesturerecognizer, collectionview

I'm new in Xamarin. I have been trying to get tap on every row of my grid but unfortunately not working. I have a `CollectionView` with A grid and inside this grid on row=1 I have another `CollectionView` with a new Grid.

My Question is when I tap on the rows onlu row=0 and row=2 is firing , not row=1 where I have Another `COllectionView`. I have attached my code bellow.

```
<RefreshView   Command="{Binding LoadAlertsCommand}" IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=TwoWay}" IsVisible="{Binding RefreshViewVisible}">
        <CollectionView x:Name="AlertsListView"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Alerts}"
                SelectionMode="None" >
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <SwipeView x:DataType="model:AlertsTable" Threshold="250">
                            <SwipeView.RightItems>
                                <SwipeItems Mode="Execute">
                                    <SwipeItem Text="Delete"
                                     BackgroundColor="#ff453a"
                                Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:AlertViewModel}}, Path=DeleteCommand}"      
                                CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                                </SwipeItems>
                            </SwipeView.RightItems>
                            <Grid Padding="15,5,15,0" x:DataType="model:AlertsTable" x:Name="Grid1" BackgroundColor="Black">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <BoxView Color="#292929" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4"/>
                            <Label x:Name="TextLabel" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"  Text="{Binding title}" TextColor="White" FontSize="20" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                                <Label x:Name="RightTextLabel" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="15" Text="{Binding date}" HorizontalOptions="Center"  VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"  TextColor="White"/>
                                <Label Text="{x:Static fontAwesome:FontAwesomeIcons.Circle}"
                                               IsVisible="{Binding wasRead}"
                                               Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3"
                                               HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                               VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                               FontSize="Medium"
                                               TextColor="White"
                                               FontFamily="fa5r"/>
                                <!--<Frame >-->
                                <CollectionView x:Name="ConditionsListView"
                                             ItemsSource="{Binding alertmetadata.Conditions}"
                                             SelectionMode="None" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.Column="0" HeightRequest="120">
                                    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <Grid x:DataType="model:AlertConditionEx">
                                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <Label Text="{Binding LeftItem.NS}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" TextColor="White"/>
                                                <Image Source="{x:Binding OS , Converter={StaticResource ImageConverter}}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                               HeightRequest="40"></Image>
                                                <Label Text="{Binding RightItem.NS}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" TextColor="White"/>
                                                <Image Source="{x:Binding OS , Converter={StaticResource ChartImageConverter}}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3"
                                               HeightRequest="40"></Image>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                                </CollectionView>
                                <Label Text="..." TextColor="White" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Large" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" IsVisible="{Binding alertmetadata.ThreeDots}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>

                            <BoxView VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"  HeightRequest="1" Color="#59595b" 
                                     Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4"/>
                            <!--</Frame>-->

                                <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <TapGestureRecognizer
                                NumberOfTapsRequired="1"
                                Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:AlertViewModel}}, Path=AlertsTapped}"       
                                CommandParameter="{Binding .}">
                                    </TapGestureRecognizer>
                                </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                            </Grid>
                        </SwipeView>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
    </RefreshView>
```

Comment: Could you add your not working code in your post?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use it like this:

```cs
Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference AlertsListView}, 
Path=BindingContext.YourCommandName}"
```

Comment: Its working exactly same as Mine. My problem is When I tap Row = 0 and Row =2  Its working , But when I tap Row=1 where my another collectioview is, Nothing Happened

Comment: This fixed it for me! The TapGestureRecognizer wasn't working inside a CollectionView DataTemplate.

Answer (score 2):

The Tap gesture would not work because `CollectionView` is different with `BoxView` or `Label` , `CollectionView` itself is able to receive action(click on item) ,so conflict will come out with external gestures.

To solve the problem , we can set extra tap gesture on the inner collectionview .

```
 <CollectionView x:Name="ConditionsListView"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding alertmetadata.Conditions}"
                 SelectionMode="None" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.Column="0" HeightRequest="120">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
          <Grid x:DataType="model:AlertConditionEx">
              <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                  <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
              </Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
              </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <Label Text="{Binding LeftItem.NS}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" TextColor="White"/>
              <Image Source="{x:Binding OS , Converter={StaticResource ImageConverter}}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HeightRequest="40"></Image>
              <Label Text="{Binding RightItem.NS}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" TextColor="White"/>
              <Image Source="{x:Binding OS , Converter={StaticResource ChartImageConverter}}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" HeightRequest="40"></Image>

               //add this code 
               <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                  <TapGestureRecognizer
                     NumberOfTapsRequired="1"
                     Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:AlertViewModel}}, Path=AlertsTapped}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}">
                  </TapGestureRecognizer>
               </Grid.GestureRecognizers>

            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
     </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

Refer to

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/57539/listview-with-mvvm-tapgesturerecognizer-not-working.

Comment: I've found that HeightRequests can cause my tap events not to fire as well, for some reason